# Changing session storage value to undefined should affect ngIf without clicking twice

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if, session-storage

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwgjjc)

When I click on button(which should make session stored variable undefined so that in other component ngIf should become false and div don't show anymore) it doesn't work first time. But when I click again it works and that div becomes hidden.

Here is my approach.

First component(This component shows first and i click on button first and then it shows second component):

```
//TS part
@SessionStorage() count: any;

onClick(){
this.count = "Any value";
}

<!-- HTML part-->
<button *ngIf="!count" (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
```

Second component:

```
//TS part
@SessionStorage() count: any;

onClick(){
this.count = undefined;
}

<!-- HTML part-->
<button *ngIf="count" (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
```

In second component I've to click twice to go to first component. I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in the second component `count` is undefined initially, and then once you click, it set its value to undefined, causing no change.

If so, make sure you initialize its value with the current count:

```
constructor(private sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService) {
  this.count = this.sessionStorageService.get('count');
}
```

Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-puzknw?file=src/app/two/two.component.ts

This should do the trick but you should probably use a service for this, and inject it to each component.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like toggle effect here but in webapp it do something else, it's just i want to produce this problem.

Comment: I believe it is still an initialization issue in component 2.

Comment: Hi, @castillo.io has given you the right way to fix your issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we need to use sessionStorageService set() methods to update the count variable.

```
this.sessionStorageService.set('count', "Any value");
```

and you can use that variable in other components like below

```
private count; 
this.count = this.sessionStorageService.get('count');

or   @SessionStorage() count: any;
```

https://angular-3izdz8.stackblitz.io

Comment: thanks for answering, I've to mark castillo.io answer as i feels it's more complete. I'll be only able to select one but I'm upvoting both.